confusing with upgrading yajra/datatable from old version 6 to version upto 9
For whoes are using yajra/laravel-datatables package!
I was using Laravel 5 and now upgrading to the version 11. Everything goes pretty well but while upgrading it, I was also checking yajra/laravel-datatables package to use the latest features.
Then I was confusing about the DataTable class which wasn't exist lower than version 9.
Because before version 9, I was doing like this Datatables::of($model)->make() in controllers, for example.
However, after version 9, looks like I need to make DataTable classes for every models I was using for datatable, is this right??
so, if I want to keep the structures and codes I already wrote in controllers, I shouldn't use the upper version 9?
And also about the view part.
Before version 9, I was just using jquery datatable function in view like below.
function dataTable(){
    dataTable = table.DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
       }],
        ajax: {
          url: "{{ route('pushlist') }}",
          crossDomain: true,
          data: function ( d ) {
              return $.extend(d,fillterOption);
          }
        },

But then in version 9, I don't need to do it anymore and just write this?
@section('content')
    {{$dataTable->table()}}
@endsection

If so, what can I do about all the details I set like fnDrawCallback, createdRow?
Where should I put those things?
